# CheckOut payment with Braintree failed

Tags: java, php, android, braintree, braintree-sandbox

When I click checkout for payment, my order not send to the server (SQL).
Here is my log:

> Braintree\Result\Error[errors=[Braintree\Error\ValidationErrorCollection/errors:[(
>   )]], params=transaction=type=sale, amount=4.4024E7,
>   paymentMethodNonce=tokencc_bc_hxvh83_fkxpvx_9bg2mr_ny5prr_7n5,
>   options=submitForSettlement=true, message=Amount is an invalid
>   format., creditCardVerification=, transaction=, subscription=,
>   merchantAccount=, verification=]

```
///file config php braintree here

//braintree_init
    braintree_init.php:
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once ("lib/autoload.php");

    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../.env"))
    {

        $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . "/../");
        $dotenv->load();
    }
    //add key value form braintree
    Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('33z8qvth85f5z6bs');
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('wh99mdq8ymvvkkms');
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('d65a6142e8e5123521143737e6a78601');
    ?>

//check out
    checkout.php:
    <?php
    require_once ("braintree_init.php");
    require_once ('lib/Braintree.php');

    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
        'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => True
        ]
    ]);
    echo $result;
    ?>

//// file main check token 

    file main.php
    <?php
    require_once ("braintree_init.php");
    require_once ('lib/Braintree.php');

result send to order failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, contact [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com)</sub>

The error message has `message=Amount is an invalid format.` included. You need to format the amount correctly. You're currently passing `4.4024E7`. You can find the guidelines for formatting values for parameters in [Braintree's developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#amount).

As an example, the transaction should be successful if you passed `4.40` as the amount value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I follow your instruction, and then I want to change currency from USD to VND and I have a problem ,